# Xcode 10.2 unable to launch simulator

Tags: macos, xcode10.2

I have recently upgraded to xcode 10.2 and I am having a strange error.
Whenever I try to launch my app I'm getting following error - Timed out trying to boot simulator after waiting 60.00s.

[image]

I have even tried do a fresh install but no luck I am always getting the same error.

Does anyone knows how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's fixed this way.
What I did is I ran this command in terminal `$ xcrun simctl erase all`.
After this I run my project again from `xcode` without even downloading anything and it worked.

Comment: worked, thanks! no need to delete all of the simulators as in the accepted answer.

Comment: A bottle of wine for you;) Worked perfectly;)

Comment: @Rahul great...bravo!

Answer (score 6):

I faced the issue in `XCode 10.1` versions. So I did `sudo xcrun simctl erase all` everytime, worked fine.

However, I updated to `XCode 10.2`, got the same error. I did the same thing, but didn't worked.

It replied me `xcrun: error: active developer path ("~/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist`, didn't find that trouble in earlier versions of XCode.

I had to reset by `sudo xcode-select --reset` and restarted my mac.

Worked fine for me now.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

1. Go to Window > Devices and Simulators, delete all the simulators, all of them.
2. Clear `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/` folder.
3. Return to Xcode and install the required simulators.