# Xcode simulator: "Unable to boot the simulator"

Tags: xcode, macos, ios-simulator, macos-catalina

**macOS:** 10.15.4 (19E287)
**Xcode:**  11.5 beta (11N605c)
**Simulator:** 
Version 11.5 (921.9)
SimulatorKit 581.9.1
CoreSimulator 704.12.1

**Error:**
[image]

Log of `/Users/rusakovic/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator.log`

```
May  5 22:03:08 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Warning>: Device DF41FCC8-DA93-47CA-AD47-4EA67FB4D560 encountered in creation state at launch.  The device will be re-created.
May  5 22:03:08 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Notice>: Could not locate default .GlobalPreferences.plist for iOS 13.5 (13.5 - 17F5054f) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-5
May  5 22:03:19 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Error>: Could not register service com.apple.PowerManagement.control: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0xfffffecc
May  5 22:03:27 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Error>: Could not register service com.apple.SystemConfiguration.configd_host: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0xfffffecc
May  5 22:03:27 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Error>: Could not register service com.apple.audio.coreaudiod: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e
May  5 22:03:27 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Error>: Could not register service com.apple.SystemConfiguration.PPPController: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e
May  5 22:03:27 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Error>: Could not register service com.apple.audio.audiohald: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e
May  5 22:03:27 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Error>: Could not register service com.apple.coreservices.lsuseractivity.simulatorsupport: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e
May  5 22:03:27 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Error>: Could not register service com.apple.FSEvents: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e
May  5 22:03:27 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Error>: Could not register service com.apple.SystemConfiguration.configd: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e
May  5 22:03:27 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Error>: Could not register service com.apple.metal.simulator.Carousel: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e
May  5 22:03:27 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Error>: Could not register service com.apple.metal.simulator.SketchBoard: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e
May  5 22:03:27 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Error>: Could not register service com.apple.metal.simulator.SpringBoard: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e
May  5 22:03:27 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Error>: Could not register service com.apple.metal.simulator.SBRendererService: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e
May  5 22:03:27 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Error>: Could not register service com.apple.IOSurface.Remote: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e
May  5 22:03:27 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Error>: Could not register service com.apple.metal.simulator.HeadBoard: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e
May  5 22:03:27 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Error>: Could not register service IndigoHIDRegistrationPort: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e
May  5 22:03:27 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Error>: Could not register service com.apple.metal.simulator.backboardd: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e
May  5 22:03:27 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Error>: Could not register service com.apple.metal.simulator: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e
May  5 22:03:27 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Error>: Could not register service com.apple.metal.simulator.PineBoard: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e
May  5 22:03:27 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Error>: Could not register service com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimFramebufferServer: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e
May  5 22:03:27 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Error>: Could not register service com.apple.CoreSimulator.host.bootstrap_port: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e
May  5 22:03:27 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Error>: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=60 "Operation timed out" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to boot the Simulator., NSLocalizedFailureReason=launchd failed to respond.}
May  5 22:03:27 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Error>: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=60 "Operation timed out" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to boot the Simulator., NSLocalizedFailureReason=launchd failed to respond.}
May  5 22:03:27 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Error>: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=60 "Operation timed out" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to boot the Simulator., NSLocalizedFailureReason=launchd failed to respond.}
May  5 22:03:27 Maxs-MBP com.apple.iphonesimulator[1433] <Error>: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=60 "Operation timed out" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=launchd failed to respond., NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to boot the Simulator.}
May  5 22:03:27 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Error>: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=165 "Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown}
May  5 22:03:27 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Error>: Error looking up host support port: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=165 "Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown}
May  5 22:03:27 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Error>: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=165 "Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown}
May  5 22:03:27 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Error>: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=165 "Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown}
May  5 22:03:27 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Error>: Error looking up host support port: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=165 "Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown}
May  5 22:03:27 Maxs-MBP CoreSimulatorService[690] <Error>: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=165 "Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown}
```

**What I tried:**

1.

```
rm -rf /Volumes/.../private/tmp
mkdir /Volumes/.../private/tmp
chmod 1777 /Volumes/.../private/tmp
chown root:wheel /Volumes/.../private/tmp
```

2. Removing all devices in Xcode.
   [image]
3. Xcode [reinstalling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33812614/3970235)

```
/Applications/Xcode.app
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
~/Library/Application Support/Xcode
~/Library/Developer/Xcode
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator
```

4. Erase all from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55701315/3970235)
   `xcrun simctl erase all`

But it's not working. Who could help to fix it?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution to this problem?